# Strange error with converting from UTC to TimeZone

Tags: c#, timezone

I have a problem with converting from UTC time to the respective local time.

What I have is UTC Time and Location Time Zone in string (Like "Eastern Standard Time").

My code:

```
private static DateTime? LocalTimeConvert(string locationTimeZone, DateTime? dateTimeUtc)
{

    var dateTimeUnspec = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTimeUtc.Value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    DateTime utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimeUnspec, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(locationTimeZone));

    return utcDateTime;
}

public static T LocalTime<T>(T value, string locationTimeZone)
{
    if (value.GetType().IsGenericType && value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
    {
        IList collection = (IList)value;

        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            VariableConvertion(element, locationTimeZone);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        VariableConvertion(value, locationTimeZone);
    }

    return value;
}


private static T VariableConvertion<T>(T value, string locationTimeZone)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = value.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in props)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?) || property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            if (property.GetValue(value) != null)
            {
                var localTime = LocalTimeConvert(locationTimeZone, DateTime.Parse(property.GetValue(value).ToString()));
                property.SetValue(value, localTime);
            }
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

The assumptions were that any value that enters the method is to search for variables that are date and change them with the appropriate local time.

Unfortunately, I have a strange bug where it converts correctly at one time and wrong at the other.

Data from LocalTimeConvert method:

### Eastern Standard Time - correct

```
    System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById returned {(UTC-05:00) Stany Zjednoczone i Kanada (czas wschodni)}    System.TimeZoneInfo
    locationTimeZone    "Eastern Standard Time" string
    dateTimeUtc {19.03.2021 15:43:07}   System.DateTime?
    dateTimeUnspec  {19.03.2021 15:43:07}   System.DateTime
    utcDateTime {19.03.2021 10:43:07}   System.DateTime
```

### Central European Standard Time - incorrect

```
    System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById returned {(UTC+01:00) Sarajewo, Skopie, Warszawa, Zagrzeb}   System.TimeZoneInfo
    locationTimeZone    "Central European Standard Time"    string
    dateTimeUtc {22.03.2021 12:58:09}   System.DateTime?
    dateTimeUnspec  {22.03.2021 12:58:09}   System.DateTime
    utcDateTime {22.03.2021 12:58:09}   System.DateTime
```

I am also wondering why I get different time on the server in the USA and different time on the server in Poland. I use pipe in angular for date: 'short': 'UTC' so I supposed to get the exact date from the database without local convertion right? Or the DateTime in C# is also converting the date to server date?

Comment: Because you are using ConvertTime which is changing time.  All computers store time in UTC and then when input a string or outputting a string uses the timezone setting on machine to automatically convert.  When you use ConvertTime you are changing the time.    Poland is +2 and EST is -4.  So if it is midnight UTC it is 8:00PM EST and 2:AM Poland time.  If you go to both machine and ask to display UTC time you will get midnight on both machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTime_System_DateTime_System_TimeZoneInfo_) of the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo)` method.

In the **Remarks** section, it says that if the `Kind` property of the source `DateTime` is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, that it is assumed to be *local*.  Since you explicitly set the kind to `Unspecified` in your code, you are not converting from UTC to the named time zone, but you are instead converting from local time to the named time zone.

In this context, "local time" means local to the time zone setting of the computer where the code is executing.  So if your server in Poland is set for Poland's time zone, then the conversion to Poland's time will be a no-op.

If your intention is to convert UTC to a specific time zone, then either the source value's `Kind` should be `DateTimeKind.Utc`, or you should use `ConvertTimeFromUtc` instead of `ConvertTime`  (the difference being, `Unspecified` kind is assumed to be `Utc` rather than `Local`).

As an aside - you've got a potential bug with `DateTime.Parse(property.GetValue(value).ToString()`.  Don't ever create a string from an object just to parse it back to an object again.  Instead, *cast* the object to unbox it to the desired type.  The tostring/parse approach often is slower and often introduces bugs related to date formats of the current culture.

Comment: Thank you!

The only one thing I had to change was ConvertTimeFromUtc. When I were searching for solutions for my problem I didn't know about that method. 

Also I've changed that bug into:

DateTime localDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(property.GetValue(value));
var localTime = LocalTimeConvert(locationTimeZone, localDateTime);
property.SetValue(value, localTime);

Thank you : )